# Prevent iframe content resizing with the iframe's dimensions, but always display the complete content

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, iframe

I can resize the iframe using a slider. When the slider is resized the content loaded within the iframe also shrinks or expands. I always want the complete content to be displayed and fit the content to the iframe's dimensions, without scrollbars. For instance in the `GIF` below, I don't want GitHub to resize but want the full webpage at all times, just scaling as a whole. Like an image

Maybe I need to adjust the `transform-scale` attribute of the content whenever the iframe's dimensions change, but how would the scale be determined at each width/height?

[image]

https://robert.ocallahan.org/2020/11/dom-recording-for-web-application-demos.html ... here you can see that it's possible. But can't seem to replicate

Comment: do you want the browser to be work in this way?

Comment: I'm not resizing the browser, but a <div>. I'm using `splitpanes`